# How to enable Azure integration in IdentityServer4 for Core 2.0?

Tags: azure, integration, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have an application that based on IdentityServer4 core 1.0. It has a working integration with Azure AD. However, after migrating the project to IdentityServer4 2.0.0-rc1 the integration no longer work. It has something to do with the broken changes from .NET Core 1.0 to Core 2.0. I following the suggestions of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

I tried to change the `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` calls to

`services.AddAuthentication()
       .AddMicrosoftAccount(...)`

or to

`services.AddAuthentication()
       .AddOpenIdConnect(...)`

But all of these only yields empty list in this query: 
`_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationSchemes()`, which is used to build the external authentication services.

Does anyone know what's the proper way to enable the Azure AD integration again?

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I figured it out. The important part is that you should no longer depend on the obsolete call: `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationSchemes()`. Instead, you should call `await _schemaProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync()` where _schemaProvider is an injected interface of IAuthenticationSchemeProvider. The other change is in Startup.cs ConfigureServices you should build the external authentication provider like this:

`services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "[custom name]"
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("[custom name]", options => {
                    options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]";
                    options.ClientId = [client id];
                });`

Note: I passed a name as the first parameter to AddOpenIdConnect, which will give a custom scheme name to this instance. This helps to show the external provider on the login page since I haven't figured out how to pass the DisplayName yet. Without this change, it will show 'openIdConnect'. Which I think is too generic and confusion, if I have many AAD integrations. Because of this scheme change, you will also need to make sure the options.DefaultChallengeScheme is set to a scheme name that you added.

Answer (score 0):

John Cheng is correct.
Just wanted to add there is a second parameter to the AddOpenIdConnect method that takes in the Display Name:

`.AddOpenIdConnect("azure", "AZURE AD", options => {})`